# How do I capture data from IoT core in a Lambda function which then inserts it into a RDS MySQL using python?

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-iot-core

I am currently publishing to AWS IoT core with my Raspberrypi using an MQTT client. Now I want to move this data into a MySQL database so that it can be used as a backend for a website that I plan on creating. I can not find a clear tutorial anywhere for an IoT beginner that explains how to write or implement a lambda function to do this. I am willing to do another architecture as long as  the data from IoT core is written into the MySQL database in near real time. It would be awesome if someone could provide some resources or an explanation with python based example code, Thank you so much!

I Have not been able to sucessfully get this connection to MySQL to work yet and would like to get this done soon.

Comment: You have to use AWS IoT Rules to forward data to other AWS Services. I'd suggest to use AWS IoT Rule to forward data to SQS and then have a lambda consuming messages from SQS. This lambda can write data to RDS. Not sure why RDS though, it is expensive....

Comment: I was given the advice for my specific use, which is near real-time data from multiple IoT devices, in the order of less than a kilobyte per IoT message, for data visualization that it was one of the best options. However, I am open to other ideas if you think that something might be better suited.

Comment: I'd would have used Timestream for time series data or Influx hosted on EC2. How much does your RDS cluster cost? RDS